# CopyAsync never runs to completion

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm copying a file from a USB stick to the LocalState folder within my app. As it's UWP I'm using

`Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ removeableDevices = Windows::Storage::KnownFolders::RemovableDevices;`

to get the USB drive path etc.

```
auto copyTask = create_task(virtualFile->CopyAsync(targetFolder, outputFilenameUwp, Windows::Storage::NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName));
while (!copyTask.is_done())
{
    Sleep(100);
}
```

The above method runs to the point that the file is fully copied to LocalState but the task never completes. It just remains in the while loop forever. I can perform a work around to check that the file has reached the right size and then jump out of the loop, but this is sub-optimal.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use  [task::then](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/task-class#then) on the `copyTask` and supply a lambda that will be invoked when the asynchronous operation completes.

Please refer to the following code:

```
auto copyTask =
    create_task(file->CopyAsync(folder, "test.jpg", NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName));
copyTask.then([](StorageFile^ copiedFile) { //This lambda will be invoked when the copyTask completes
    String^ name = copiedFile->Name;
    });
```

The input argument to the lambda in `copyTask.then` is the result that the `copyTask` operation produces when the task completes. For more information about consuming an async operation by using a task, you could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps#consuming-an-async-operation-by-using-a-task).

Comment: This doesn't work either. There seems to be a problem that the state of the task doesn't change... The status checks work with other examples but specifically not this one.

Comment: Could you please tell me the size of the file you want to copy, and if you have registered file types to be copied in the app manifest file, referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card#what-you-can-access)? You could try to copy the file in another disk such as D disk in File Explorer and use your app to copy the file in D disk so that you could check if the problem is related to the USB stick.

Comment: The size of the file is approx 10GB and I've also got an NVMe SSD, whether that has something to do with it. I've just tried to transfer between local folders: LocalState -> LocalState and the same problem occurred... Very strange, as I say it works for other types of task, but copying seems to be problematic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, so there's an update. The task does run to completion, but it takes a while. 10-15 seconds after the file has been copied the status the changes. Sorry for the mess around but this is still not the expected behaviour for something like this?

Comment: If you copied a file which size is approximate 10 GB, a period of time is needed. Length of time spent is based on the performance of your machine. You said it takes 10-15 seconds after the file has been copied, if the time is used for a 10GB file, it is reasonable.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just seems to be a big delay because using std::filesystem::copy_file (synchronous) returns immediately. I wouldn't have thought that clean up after copying the file would take so long... Out of curiousity, what's happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was being too impatient, once the file has copied there is some housekeeping that needs to take place. Once this is done, the correct state is set.